# Get item fully visible or not in Recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am making an android app in which `RecyclerView` consist list of GIFs, Now I want to develop such functionality like when GIF item is completely visible to the user then and then it starts loading, once it slightly looses the focus of user it should stop loading.

I have displayed GIF in recyclerview now the only part remain is how to get that such GIF is fully visible or looses focus. I want such code inside adapter which indicated that this item is fully visible and this item looses focus.

**MY Adapter class**

```
public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


private List<FeedModel> feedList;
Context context;

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(feedList.get(position));

    new GifDataDownloader() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final byte[] bytes) {
            holder.gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
            holder.gifImageView.startAnimation();
        }
    }.execute(feedList.get(position).getUrl());


}

public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<FeedModel> feedList) {
    this.feedList = feedList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedList.size();
}

public void setGridData(ArrayList<FeedModel> feedList) {
    this.feedList = feedList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    FeedModel item;
    GifImageView gifImageView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        gifImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);
    }

    public void setData(FeedModel item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

**My activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
ImageView imageView1;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
FeedAdapter mAdapter;
ProgressBar progressBar;
GridLayoutManager manager;
Spinner countrySpinner;
ArrayList<FeedModel> feedList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    feedList = new ArrayList<>(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        FeedModel feedModel = new FeedModel();
        feedModel.setUrl("https://media.tenor.com/images/925bfbaad2f947987bcf18b9167b3326/tenor.gif");
        feedList.add(feedModel);
    }


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getApplicationContext(), feedList);
    manager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioAra I added my code please help

Comment: Check this https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager .You may need to change it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to used glide to show image and gif etc. it is take all senior that you define .

Add below dependency into app level gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

then after used in adapter like this way..

```
private Context context;
  // define context into constructor 
  public RecyclerviewAdapter(List<StepsItem> stepsItems, Context context) {
    this.stepsItems = stepsItems;
    this.context = context;
}

 Glide.with(context).load(yoururl).into(holder.mIvIcon);
```

Answer (score -1):

Start gif after your view is created like in `onstart()` method 
And when you want to stop the `gif` when user is no more interact with app , stop the gif in `onpause()` method.

Comment: how will you detect this `user is no more interact with app` ?

Comment: when the app is on foreground and user click power button and screen power off in this case onpause method is called.